# Division of column values from 2 file for matching id and header

Tags: awk

I am having two large file.

**test.txt**

```
Id      sub_id  s_1     s_2     s_3     s_4     s_5     c_1     c_2     ct_1    ct_2
A       a       1       4       3       0       0       1       2       1       1
A       b       0       0       3       4       3       3       3       1       2
A       c       4       4       4       1       1       0       9       7       8
B       d       1       3       2       7       0       5       2       8       5
B       e       8       7       4       0       8       4       2       11      30
```

**test1.txt**

```
Id      s_1     s_2     s_3     s_4     s_5     c_1     c_2     ct_1    ct_2
A       5       8       10      5       4       4       14      9       11
B       9       10      6       7       8       9       4       19      35
```

**expected output**

```
Id      sub_id  s_1     s_2     s_3     s_4     s_5     c_1     c_2     ct_1    ct_2
A       a       0.2     0.5     0.3     0       0       0.25    0.142857        0.111111        0.0909091
A       b       0       0       0.3     0.8     0.75    0.75    0.214286        0.111111        0.181818
A       c       0.8     0.5     0.4     0.2     0.25    0       0.642857        0.777778        0.727273
B       d       0.111111        0.3     0.333333        1       0       0.555556        0.5     0.421053        0.142857
B       e       0.888889        0.7     0.666667        0       1       0.444444        0.5     0.578947        0.857143
```

I am comparing 1st column of test1.txt file with test.txt file and if matched i am calculation value by diving columns from test.txt file by test1.txt file. For am smaller file and without considering column header I can do this by

`awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$1;B[$1]=$2; C[$1]=$3; D[$1]=$4; E[$1]=$5; F[$1]=$6; G[$1]=$7; H[$1]=$8; I[$1]=$9; J[$1]=$10; next}FNR==1{print $0}(FNR>1 && A[$1]){print $1, $2, $3/B[$1], $4/C[$1], $5/D[$1], $6/E[$1], $7/F[$1], $8/G[$1], $9/H[$1], $10/I[$1], $11/J[$1]}' test1.txt test.txt`

But for files with 1000s columns, whats the best way to do this? Also can the division be made by between columns with matching headers between the two files?

**INPUT FILE EDITED to show representation of different column order**

**test11.txt**

```
Id      sub_id  s_1     s_2     s_3     s_4
A       a       1       4       3       0
A       b       0       0       3       0
A       c       4       4       4       0
B       d       1       3       2       7
B       e       8       7       4       0
```

**test12.txt**

```
Id      s_1     s_2     s_4     s_3
A       5       8       0       10
B       9       10      7       6
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
Id      sub_id  s_1     s_2     s_3     s_4
A       a       0.2     0.5     0.3     0
A       b       0       0       0.3     0
A       c       0.8     0.5     0.4     0
B       d       0.111111        0.3     0.333333        1
B       e       0.888889        0.7     0.666667        0
```

Comment: What should be output if a value in `test1.txt` is `0` - 0, NaN, Inf or something else? wrt `can the division be made by between columns with matching headers` - sure but if the headers can have different values and/or the same values but in a different order between the 2 input files then you should demonstrate that in your sample input/output so we have something realistic to test with and can see how to handle columns whose headers aren't present in the other file or are present in a different order (which order do they get output).

Comment: @EdMorton I am editing the input file with respect to column order. Regarding the test1.txt value being 0; in that scenario test.txt column will be also 0; and the expected output  for such division will be 0,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR {
   for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i)
      if (FNR==1)
         h1[i] = $i
      else
         map[$1,h1[i]] = ($i != 0 ? $i : 1)
    next
}
{
   for (i=3; i<=NF; ++i)
      if (FNR==1)
         h2[i] = $i
      else
         $i /= map[$1,h2[i]]
} 1' test12.txt test11.txt | column -t


Id  sub_id  s_1       s_2  s_3       s_4
A   a       0.2       0.5  0.3       0
A   b       0         0    0.3       0
A   c       0.8       0.5  0.4       0
B   d       0.111111  0.3  0.333333  1
B   e       0.888889  0.7  0.666667  0
```

Comment: this work perfect if column header were in same order in both input files; but if input files column order changes; it it dont give expected results.

Comment: my apologies for not providing examples while asking. I have added new input file examples. Thanks